# Can't launch a web browser in OS X via "open_new"? (Works fine on windows)

Tags: python, macos

The following program opens a browser and navigates to www.cnn.com on Windows, but in OS X nothing happens.  I'm not sure why.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new("www.cnn.com")
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new("http://www.cnn.com")
```

On OS X, this is converted to the following shell command:

```
echo 'open location "http://www.cnn.com"' | osascript
```

For whatever reason, `open location www.cnn.com` does not work in osascript on OS X.

*This was tested on OS X Lion.*